# On click functionality of Button Inside ListView in Wicket Framework

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicketstuff

Im populating a table using ListView component in wicket.The last column of my table is button. So for each row I'll have a button in the last column.What I'm trying to implement is onlick of the button I need to delete the appropriate row. So for this I need to get the current index of the list on click of button. How to achieve/get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extend Ajax button and pass the row reference (item) in the constructor...then you can do anything you want..by overriding the onSubmit method

Example:

```
private class SpecialButton extends AjaxButton {
    final Item<Object> rowItem;

    public SpecialButton(final String id, final Item<Object> rowItem) {
        super(id);

        this.rowItem = rowItem;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form<?> form) {
        // here you cand do everything you want with the item and the model object of the item.(row)
        Object object = rowItem.getModelObject();
    }

}
```

You should replace Object from `Item<Object>` with your reapeater model. After creating this private class you can reuse it for every row in your repeater.

If you want to delete that row you just have to remove the model from the list used to generate the repeater and refresh the repeater container(Wicket does not allow you to refresh the repeater by adding it to the target...instead you have to add the repeater continer.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the repeaters Wicket Examples page to understand how to use `ListView` and other repeaters:

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/

You can get the current index of the list from `item.getIndex()`

```
protected void populateItem(final ListItem<T> item) {
    int index = item.getIndex();
    ...
```

Comment: yeh.But this is possible only while populating the listview. So its not possible to achieve it on click of the button :-(

Comment: When you click the button your page is rendered again, or are you using an AJAX link ?

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem. If you update the ListView list model the row must be removed after the page render. Can you show us some code?

Comment: My code is in remote machine.As reputation is less than 10 for me, i couldn't even post an image .As per the code, always the index is coming  inside onSubmit as the index of last index of list because onSubmit will be invoked after populating the list view and it it always holds the index of last object.

Answer (score 0):

Look here for inspirations on how to do it properly (without index):

[Wicket ListView not refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353732/wicket-listview-not-refreshing)